# ss command take 2 lines for each result

Tags: networking, command-line

I used `netstat -anlptu` to check for open ports.
This command is now somewhat deprecated so I start using `ss -anptu` but each entry takes 2 lines. The result is not practical.
I use Debian.

`netstat -anlptu`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.106:xxxxx     192.0.x.y:443          ESTABLISHED 5081/firefox
```

Easy to read and clear.

`ss -anptu`:

```
tcp    LISTEN     0      20                                                       127.0.0.1:25                                                                           *:*
 users:(("exim4",pid=823,fd=3))
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                                                              *:22                                                                        *:*                  
 users:(("sshd",pid=807,fd=3))
tcp    ESTAB      0      272                                                  192.168.1.200:22                                                            78.224.x.y:36028              
 users:(("sshd",pid=849,fd=3),("sshd",pid=840,fd=3))
tcp    LISTEN     0      20                                                             ::1:25                                                                          :::*                  
 users:(("exim4",pid=823,fd=4))
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                                                             :::22                                                                       :::*                  
 users:(("sshd",pid=807,fd=4))
```

This is clearly not easy to read.
Some columns are not aligned.

If I redirect to `less` or `more`:

```
tcp    LISTEN     0      20     127.0.0.1:25                    *:*                   users:(("exim4",pid=823,fd=3))
tcp    LISTEN     0      128       *:22                 *:*                   users:(("sshd",pid=807,fd=3))
tcp    ESTAB      0      40     192.168.1.200:22              78.224.x.y:36028               users:(("sshd",pid=849,fd=3),("sshd",pid=840,fd=3))
tcp    LISTEN     0      20      ::1:25                   :::*                   users:(("exim4",pid=823,fd=4))
tcp    LISTEN     0      128      :::22                :::*                   users:(("sshd",pid=807,fd=4))
```

Each entry takes one line, but columns are not aligned. Once again not easy to read

--> how can I have a readable output with `ss`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `column`.  For example:

```
ss -anpt | column -t -x | less
```

I get output like:

```
State       Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local                       Address:Port                  Peer                                         Address:Port
LISTEN      0       100     127.0.0.1:143               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN      0       100     0.0.0.0:465                 0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN      0       128     0.0.0.0:42449               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN      0       10      0.0.0.0:5298                0.0.0.0:*                     users:(("pidgin",pid=30003,fd=19))
```

Note: i run a terminal that is 282 columns wide (a maximum width terminal on my 1440p screen with Liberation Mono Regular 11).  YMMV on narrower terminals.

`column` performs a similar, but not identical, job as the `columns` program from the `autogen`.  It does a good job of auto-formatting text into tabulated columns.

I'm not sure where the original source for `column` came from, but on debian systems, it's in the `bsdmainutil` package.  It may be in a similarly named package on other Linux distributions.

```
Package: bsdmainutils
Version: 11.1.2
Description-en: collection of more utilities from FreeBSD
 This package contains lots of small programs many people expect to find when
 they use a BSD-style Unix system.
 .
 It provides banner (as printerbanner), calendar, col, colcrt, colrm, column,
 from (as bsd-from), hexdump (or hd), look, lorder, ncal (or cal), ul, and
 write (as bsd-write).
 .
 This package used to contain whois and vacation, which are now distributed in
 their own packages. Also here was tsort, which is now in the "coreutils"
 package.
```

The `/usr/share/doc/bsdmainutils/copyright` file in the package says:

> This is a collection of programs from 4.4BSD-Lite that have not (yet)
>   been re-written by FSF as GNU.  It was constructed for inclusion in
>   Debian Linux.  As programs found here become available from GNU sources,
>   they will be replaced.

and

> This package may be redistributed under the terms of the UCB BSD
>   license:
>
> Copyright (C) 1980 -1998 The Regents of the University of California.
>   All rights reserved.